# async.series() continues to execute next functions despite errors

Tags: node.js, express, async.js, keystonejs

I'm using the async.series() control flow from caolan's async module. U
nlike the doc's explanation that it should excute all functions in sequence, one after the other and stop when one calls its callback with an error; mine actually calls the main callback if one of the functions gets an erro but then happily continues to execute the rest of the functions in sequence.

```
async.series([

    function (cb) {

        if (!req.body.join_firstname || !req.body.join_lastname || !req.body.join_email || !req.body.join_password) {
            req.flash('error', 'Please enter a name, email and password.');
            cb(true);
        }

        if (req.body.join_password !== req.body.join_passwordConfirm) {
            req.flash('error', 'Passwords must match.');
            cb(true);
        }

        if (req.body.join_email !== req.body.join_emailConfirm) {
            req.flash('error', 'Emails must match.');
            cb(true);
        }

        cb(null);

    },

    function (cb) {

        keystone.list('User').model.findOne({
            email: req.body.join_email
        }, function (err, user) {

            if (err || user) {
                req.flash('error', 'User already exists with that email address.');
                cb(true);
            }

            cb(null);

        });

    },

    function (cb) {

        var userData = {
            name: {
                first: req.body.join_firstname,
                last: req.body.join_lastname
            },
            email: req.body.join_email,
            password: req.body.join_password
        };

        var User = keystone.list('User').model,
            newUser = new User(userData);

        newUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                //if there's an error, don't send activation mail
                cb(err);
            } else {
                newUser.activationEmail(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        //if we can't send activation email,
                        //delete user from db to prevent re-registration failing because of non-unique email
                        keystone.list('User').model.findOne({
                            email: req.body.join_email
                        }).remove(function (err) {
                            req.flash('error', "Couldn't send an activation email. Contact support if this problem persists.");
                            cb(true);
                        });
                    } else {
                        cb(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
], function (err) {
    if (err) return next();
    req.flash('success', "Hi, " + req.body.join_firstname + "! We've sent you an activation email. Please check your inbox and spam folder.");
    return res.redirect('/');
});
```

For example, when I purposely enter the wrong password confirm value, it throws an error, executes the callback and `return next();` and then just continues, even saving the user in the db. Obviously that was not the intended result.

Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want execution of a current function to stop, it's not enough to call a callback. For instance:

```
function(cb) {

    if (!req.body.join_firstname || !req.body.join_lastname || !req.body.join_email || !req.body.join_password) {
        req.flash('error', 'Please enter a name, email and password.');
        cb(true);  // will add this callback to the stack
    }
    // continuing here
    // ...
}
```

Either change your if-then-construct:

```
function(cb) {

    if (!req.body.join_firstname || !req.body.join_lastname || !req.body.join_email || !req.body.join_password) {
        req.flash('error', 'Please enter a name, email and password.');
        cb(true);  // will add this callback to the stack
    } else if (req.body.join_password !== req.body.join_passwordConfirm) {
        //...
    }
    // no more code here
}
```

or return:

```
function(cb) {

    if (!req.body.join_firstname || !req.body.join_lastname || !req.body.join_email || !req.body.join_password) {
        req.flash('error', 'Please enter a name, email and password.');
        return cb(true);  // will add this callback to the stack and return
    }
    // will only be executed if the if is false
    // ...
}
```

Comment: OP can also use `else` for the same purpose

Comment: Yes @soulcheck, I edited the post to show that also as example.

Comment: In my example, changing all cb(true) and cb(null) to return cb(...) stops the execution of further functions after an error is thrown. However, after calling this function a second time, it still stops further execution of the functions after an error but async now throws the following error:

Comment: In my example, changing all cb(true) and cb(null) to return cb(...) stops the execution of further functions after an error is thrown. However, after calling this function a second time, it still stops further execution of the functions after an error but async now throws the following error:Error: Callback was already called.

Comment: How are you calling it a second time? Async.js hat a system in place that prevents you from creating a callback which is executed more then once, see https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js, Line #19

Comment: It gets executed on POST submit of a form.

Comment: I would have to see how you expose your API. If the browser starts a new request, the above calls to async should all be newly instantiated.

Maybe you can create a new question for that issue?